# display text on the 3D space Three.js

Tags: three.js

can any one help me to display text on the 3D space Three.js.

Simple I want function that get the message and coordinate to display. and function to remove the text. I tried for two week but i give up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have look at this

http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_geometry_text.html#FF0075111#three.js

set the coordinates as the `mesh.position`

Comment: Thanks It's helpfull